# Application keeps crashing and is very laggy: IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for dimension 0 with size 0

Tags: python, yolo, index-error, roboflow

```
import cv2
import argparse
import pandas as pd
from ultralytics import YOLO
import supervision as sv
import numpy as np
from supervision.tools.detections import Detections, BoxAnnotator
from supervision.tools.line_counter import LineCounter, LineCounterAnnotator
from supervision.draw.color import ColorPalette
from supervision import *


def parse_arguments() -> argparse.Namespace:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="YOLOv8 live")
    parser.add_argument(
        "--webcam-resolution", 
        default=[1280, 720], 
        nargs=2, 
        type=int
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

def main():
    args = parse_arguments()
    frame_width, frame_height = args.webcam_resolution

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, frame_width)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, frame_height)

    model = YOLO("yolov8l.pt")
    # dict maping class_id to class_name
    CLASS_NAMES_DICT = model.model.names
    # class_ids of interest - car, motorcycle, bus and truck
    CLASS_ID = [2, 3, 5, 7, 9]


    box_annotator = BoxAnnotator(
        color= ColorPalette(),
        thickness=2,
        text_thickness=2,
        text_scale=1
    )

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        results = model(frame, agnostic_nms=True)[0]
        detections = Detections(
                xyxy=results[0].boxes.xyxy.cpu().numpy(),
                confidence=results[0].boxes.conf.cpu().numpy(),
                class_id=results[0].boxes.cls.cpu().numpy().astype(int)
            )
        labels = [
            f"{CLASS_NAMES_DICT[class_id]} {confidence:0.2f}"
            for _, confidence, class_id, _
            in detections
        ]
        frame = box_annotator.annotate(
            frame =frame, 
            detections=detections, 
            labels=labels
        ) 
        
        cv2.imshow("yolov8", frame)

        if (cv2. waitKey(20)& 0xFF==ord('d')):
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So the above code is me trying to use live camera feed to detect vehicles and to draw a line to detect entrace and exiting of the vehicles. The code runs but it crashes after a few seconds and the time before crash is not consistent. It also returns this error.

```
return Boxes(self.boxes[idx], self.orig_shape)
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for dimension 0 with size 0
(base)
```

I believe the code is ending when it doesn't detect anything. Could you help me find out the cause of this issue?

Comment: Where does it fail. Please show proper full error. Perhaps a bad frame or blank frame. That might cause you not to get any shape. Test your shape before trying to use it.

Comment: 0: 384x640 (no detections), 827.7ms
Speed: 0.0ms preprocess, 827.7ms inference, 1.0ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 640, 640)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 97, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 71, in main
    xyxy=results[0].boxes.xyxy.cpu().numpy(),
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\yolo\engine\results.py", line 272, in __getitem__
    return Boxes(self.boxes[idx], self.orig_shape)
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for dimension 0 with size 0
(base)  @fmw42 this is the whole error.

Comment: And at what line in your code above does it fail? Please point that out as  this forum does not show line numbers. But the error is rather clear. You have a box with zero dimensions and need to trap that. It is likely a blank frame.

Comment: hi, at line 71 it throws the error (xyxy=results[0].boxes.xyxy.cpu().numpy(),). I understand it means it's trying to read an empty box which is why it throws an error but how do I make an if statement of some sort to allow it to run regardless of blank frame or not

Comment: `print(type(results))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is the problem is you do:

```py
results = model(frame, agnostic_nms=True)[0]
```

and

```py
xyxy=results[0].boxes.xyxy.cpu().numpy()
```

What I mean by this is that you access the first element of an iterable object two times - essentially, you do `model(frame, agnostic_nms=True)[0][0]`.

Just replace corresponding lines with those:

```py
results = model(frame, agnostic_nms=True)[0]
detections = Detections(
    xyxy=results.boxes.xyxy.cpu().numpy(),
    confidence=results.boxes.conf.cpu().numpy(),
    class_id=results.boxes.cls.cpu().numpy().astype(int)
)
```

Comment: hey, you're the youtube video dude I got this from. You developed this roboflow and yolo. Your videos are amazing and helping my internship rn. Thanks alot man. Love the content. But this is correct. I figured it out afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check whether you detected something or not before you start extracting bbox data:

```py
results = model.predict(source="0", show=True, stream=True, classes=0, device='cpu')
for i, result in enumerate(results):
    boxes = result.boxes
    if boxes is not None:
        ...
```

Comment: i already solved it but this looks interesting for another problem. Thank you